# Variadic template resolution in VS2013 - Error C3520

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, visual-studio-2013, variadic-templates

What's wrong with this code?

```
enum LogLevel {
    LogLevel_Error = 1,
    LogLevel_Warning = 2,
    LogLevel_Info = 3,
    LogLevel_Debug = 4
};

LogLevel GetLogLevel() {return LogLevel_Debug;};

void Write(const std::string& message) {};

void Write(LogLevel level, std::stringstream& ss) {
    if (level > GetLogLevel())
        return;
    Write(ss.str());
}

template<typename Arg> void Write(LogLevel level, std::stringstream& ss, Arg arg) {
    if (level > GetLogLevel())
        return;
    ss << arg;
    Write(ss.str());
}

template<typename First, typename... Rest> void Write(LogLevel level, std::stringstream& ss, First first, Rest... rest) {
    if (level > GetLogLevel())
        return;
    ss << first;
    Write(level, ss, rest); // Error C3520, see below
}

Write(std::stringstream(), "Hello", (const char*)" World!", 1);
```

I tried to create a recursive/variadic template for logging [just as in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn439779.aspx), but I just can't rid of error C3520 (`C3520: 'P' : parameter pack must be expanded in this context.`). Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is it (god forbid) a compiler bug?

Comment: Please elaborate a bit! State error messages literally in questions, and mark the lines where they occur.

Comment: Clarified in the question. Sorry, was too frustrated to notice :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see the following issues:

1. `rest` needs to be expanded:

   ```
   Write(level, ss, rest...);
   ```
2. `Write` is supposed to take a log level as its first argument:

   ```
   Write(GetLogLevel(), std::stringstream(), "Hello", (const char*)" World!", 1);
   ```
3. You can't pass a temporary `std::stringstream` to an lvalue reference:

   ```
   std::stringstream ss;
   Write(GetLogLevel(), ss, "Hello", (const char*)" World!", 1);
   ```

Comment: Point 3 is not really correct, it works. P1 is what's the problem, thank you! Other correct answer first, though.

Comment: @DarkWanderer It's not correct? It shouldn't work if you pass a temporary. Edit: A distant memory is telling me that this might be a MSVC extension?

Comment: It's not _supposed_ to work, but VC++ permits binding temporaries to non-const lvalue references as an extension (with a level 4 warning as diagnostic). Technically the code is very wrong and non-portable.

Comment: @DarkWanderer In other words, don't do it. :D

Comment: @DarkWanderer The problem you **asked about** is solved by P1, P2 is an additional problem that Joseph pointed out and that, of course, also needs to be fixed.

Comment: Note to myself - never make mistakes when commenting on SO :P Corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need

```
Write(level, ss, rest...);
//                   ^^^ Note these dots!
```

Comment: Damn it, missed it... Accepting this because this answer was first, but (due credit) Joseph Mansfield's one is pretty valuable too.

Comment: @DarkWanderer Please accept Joseph's answer. It should not just be about who is first, you should also reward people going the extra mile and provide *more* help than you asked for :)

Comment: Hands down, no questions, doing just that! :)